# What is the value of a concept specialization that recursively depends on itself?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++-concepts, c++20

Let's consider this code:

```
template<class T>
concept Range = requires(T& v){
    {begin(v)};
    {end(v)};
    };
namespace defaults{
    template<class T>
    auto begin(T& v) -> decltype(v.begin());
    template<class T>
    auto end(T& v) -> decltype(v.end());
    }

//naive "customization points"!
auto begin(Range auto& v){
    defaults::begin(v);
    }
auto end(Range auto& v){
    defaults::end(v);
    }

struct my_range{
    int * begin();
    int * end();
    } rng;

auto it = begin(rng); //BOOM
```

Inside the concept definition of `Range` the template function `begin(Range auto& v)` is found by ADL for the argument of type `my_range`. So `begin(v)` well-formed-ness depends on `Range<my_range>` and `Range<my_range>` depends on `begin(v)` well-formed-ness.

What is supposed to report the compiler in this case?

<sub>gcc 8.2 (concept TS) crashes and the branch of clang which implements concepts reports a recursive template instantiation depth exceeded.</sub>

Comment: Best guess would be ill-formed, ndr. There's a rule somewhere about not defining concepts recursively, this seems in line with that to me.

Comment: The standard almost never requires the compiler to report any specific thing. If the standard requires a diagnostic for ill-formed code (which is the default case), then it's up to the implementation to decide what diagnostic to provide. The compiler crashing with a message would be considered a diagnostic and thus, if the standard requires such a thing, that would satisfy it.

Comment: @NicolBolas I know that. But is not it a failure of the language specification: concepts were intended to help development of generic code. I use concepts since two years now. And since now I have adopted a realy strict layering in my project, just to avoid this hard to find bug: first include file contained "axiomatic" symbols (like an unconstrained begin), which never refers to any concepts, then primitive type traits, which do not use concepts, then concepts which only refers to the primitive type traits, and primitive axiomatic symbols. But I cannot force library users to this discipline.

Comment: @NicolBolas ... the consequence is that this bug is going to happen. And the more complex will be the library more frequently will happen this bug. Finding the source of the bug is really a pain. Without noticing it, concepts forced a strong layering of code an library, it is not more possible to use forwarding declaration as it used to be. I expect that if compilers don't provide a clear diagnostic for this bug, concepts are going to be hated!

Comment: @Oliv: "*the consequence is that this bug is going to happen*" Yes. Just like infinite recursion or infinite loops happen. "*I expect that if compilers don't provide a clear diagnostic for this bug*" And what exactly does that have to do with the *standard*? You tagged your question with "language-lawyer", which means you want to know how the standard defines language requirements and maybe whether a particular compiler is following them.

Comment: @NicolBolas Language deputy often are language lawyer.

Comment: @NicolBolas It will not be like infinite loop recursions. Inside the code the recursion only happens with the function selected by overload resolution. For concepts it will happen for many viable functions! That is explosive! (I say that in case you are a commitee member)

Comment: @NicolBolas It is worst in fact, during viable function selection, constraint checking is performed before argument to parameter conversion check! It will be very easy to get a compilation failure or a crash of the compiler, even if the code is would be well formed without those recursion. The consequence is that a miss-formed constraint due to this recursion will cause compilation failure of unrelated parts of the code!